# Automatic suspension no longer works after 'systemctl mask sleep.target' + 'systemctl unmask sleep.target'

Tags: systemd, kde, power-management, suspend

My laptop is running KDE on LinuxMint 18.3. Automatic suspend was working so far. KDE version is 5.8.9, Framworks version 5.36.0. QT version 5.6.1, kernel version 4.10.0-38-generic.

In the Energy Saving module's dialog box, Suspend session is turned on and set to, e.g. after 10 minutes.

I then did a 'systemctl mask sleep.target' as root, followed by 'systemctl unmask sleep.target' to restore it.

After this, automatic suspension no longer works. After 10 minutes, the laptop is still not suspended. The screen is blank and locked. After I unlock, the Authentication Required dialog box is showing up and is asking for password, instead of suspension being done automatically.

Manual suspend via pm-suspend still works.

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE 2019-05-28 #1**: Output of `systemctl list-unit-files | grep sleep`:

```
systemd-hybrid-sleep.service       static
hybrid-sleep.target                static
sleep.target                       static
```

**UPDATE 2019-05-28 #2**: The problem seems to heal itself after reboot. But when system is not rebooted, after doing `systemctl mask sleep.target` followed by `systemctl unmask sleep.target`, automatic suspend action is blocked by the Authentication Required dialog box.

**UPDATE 2019-05-28 #3**: I'm still trying to find out how to reproduce this consistently. This does not always happen. After I reboot (and the problem disappears), if I do `systemctl mask sleep.target` + unmask, automatic suspend sometimes still runs OK.

**UPDATE 2019-05-29**: To reproduce this, after masking, let time pass so automatic suspend timeout (from Energy Saving setting) is triggering. Then unmask. Afterwards, everytime automatic suspend timeout is triggering, the Authentication Required dialog box is showing instead of automatically suspending.

Comment: what's the output of `systemctl list-unit-files | grep sleep` ?

Comment: @intika Updated question with the information

Comment: can you add the output of `systemctl list-unit-files --user` and `systemctl list-unit-files` also please explain what are you trying to achieve with mark/unmark? suspend settings should not require you to play with systemd settings

Comment: Maybe you need to do `systemctl daemon-reload` after unmasking ?

Comment: @intika I am trying to prevent laptop from going into sleep. This is one recommended way when system is running systemd.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET Tried that just now, didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Just install the plasmoid "Caffeine Plus" you will be able to prevent/revert sleep with a click

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm aware of Caffeine and will probably use that instead. Just curious about this issue still.

Comment: Well i guess that daemon-reload is not enough to re enable the sleep target, and service relying on sleep.target needs to be reloaded as well to make it work, you can try to start systemd-suspend.service, this will make the system sleep then check if the sleep work after that or try to enable/disable suspend service instead of masking/unmasking the target (because reboot solve the issue).

Comment: "systemctl disable systemd-suspend.service" does not prevent automatic suspend. And in general, I think "disable" won't prevent a service/target from being started. It only makes the service/target not started at boot.

Comment: "systemctl mask systemd-suspend.service" does prevent automatic suspend on my laptop, FYI. And the same thing happens, after unmasking, automatic suspend no longer works; it asks Authentication.